# Command line showing only question marks at non-English computer

Tags: windows, java, language, i18n

I have a Windows computer that's using a non-English language. I installed Java to make a keystore to my server. But when I execute it, it only shows '??????'

For example

```
C:\Java\bin\keytool> keytool.exe -list
??????
```

I have tried using the language pack, but it needs to restart, and this server must online for 24 hours. How can I change it to English? Or any alternatives here?

Comment: It is possible you simply need to set the default encoding, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469163/how-to-set-the-default-encoding-in-windows-xp

Comment: it needs restart

Comment: http://wandersick.blogspot.com/p/change-non-english-command-line.html this will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use UTF-8 encoding in a command line.
Use `>chcp <codepage>` command to check or set proper code page, where the proper code page for UTF-8 is 65001. And set [Lucida Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2Z9R.png)  font after all

Comment: I wonder if the OP will reply??